# MS Reporting Services Page break question

Tags: reporting-services

I'm **using MS Reporting Services** to display my Data. In the report file, I created a **table** with grouping, precisely with **3 groups**. (Reason for this is that I'm doing a right / left join directly in SQL which I supply then to the DataSet).

```
Line1 (Group1): Subject: =Fields!Subject.Value .... this is a main group = grouped by s_id
Line2 (Group2): Responsibles: =Fields!Name.Value ... group by r_id, parent= s_id
Line3 (Group3): ResponsibleOtherProjects:=Fields!ProjectName.Value...group by o_id,parent=r_id
```

Every thing works fine, but there's one huge problem. If the data in a subgroup is longer that the physical page height, **it jumps on the other page**.. and so on..
The result is consequently a very ugly report with much blank space.

Any idea how to tell MS Rep. Services not to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So you want group1, 2 and 3 to be on the same page? I suggest you place a page break after group 1 (or two if it makes sense). This way (if the content fits in one page) you will have all groups in one page.

If your content is too big to fit into one page then changing the line height, font, font size, and padding should allow you to fit more content into one page.

Comment: I want it consecutively. Through many pages. Without any whitespace and pagebreaks. The problem is when the group3 is too big then the whole group 2 jumps to another page, because it thinks there will be more place or something. Then a white space on the 1st page appears..

Comment: try setting the KeepTogether Option to true in Group 1. You also can expand the dynamic page size to make it much bigger. This way when you view it, it will appear on one continguous space. Are you planning to print the report?

Comment: Yes it's for printing purposes.